# What does $a $< $b $<c mean?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, notation

1.What does $a $< $b $<c really mean?

Somebody says that it means "3 distinct numbers". 
and for example they said 1$\le$a$\lt$b$\lt$c$\le$N means 3 numbers between 1 and N.

2.We want to say "3 distinct numbers";
 Then Why don't we use 1$\le$a$\ne$b$\ne$c$\le$N instead of 1$\le$a$\lt$b$\lt$c$\le$N ?

3.If we want to show 3 numbers that are not necessarily distinct, It is not possible to do that except with $\le$. am I right?

Would you please explain about all of these 3 questions? Thank you.

Comment: Doesnt $a<b$ already imply that $a \neq b$?  If not, that is what $a \leq b$ is for.  Writing $a < b < c$ implies they are distinct and puts them in a certain order.

Comment: Saying $a \neq b \neq c$ is sloppy.  For instance, if you write $1 \neq 2 \neq 1$ is that okay?

Comment: $a<b<c$ adds that $a$ is the ssmallest, $c$ the largest and $b$ is between the other two.

Comment: To add to Randall's comment, $1\le a\ne b\ne c\le N$ is even worse because it's unclear if the inequalities mean that all of $a,b,c$ are between $1$ and $N$, or only that $1\le a$ and $c\le N$. In general, statements $a\,R\,b$ and $b\,S\,c$ (where $R,S$ are relational symbols like $=,\equiv,\ge,<$) should only be chained together as $a\,R\,b\,S\,c$ if $R$ and $S$ are the same transitive relation, or closely related relations (like $<$ and $\le$) for which $a\,R\,b$ and $b\,S\,c$ imply a relation between $a$ and $c$ (probably either $a\,R\,c$ or $a\,S\,c$).

Comment: Technically.  Neither $a<b<c$ nor $a\neq b\neq c$ is correct, formally, because $<$ and $\neq$ are *binary relations.* But wr allow the first because $a<b$ and $b<c$ means $a<c.$ So we are really not doing anything new. But this does not hold for $\neq,$ So if $a\neq b\neq c$ is meant to mean they are distinct, this means we get a come complicated kind of relation definition. We could certainly use that definition, but mathematicians have chosen not to because of the potential confusion.

Comment: Also, your notation would include the triples $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$ and $(1,3,2),$ which are the same triple. But $a<b<c$ ensures we only get the triple once.

Comment: Are you familiar with the phrase "Without loss of generality"? When you say "Let $a,b,c$ be distinct numbers, say $a < b < c$", this means exactly: "Let $a,b,c$ be distinct numbers. WLOG, we may assume $a<b<c$."

Comment: @Randall Thank you so much for your detailed explanation. yes you are right and a<b implies that a!=b and yes. that notation is sloppy. By the way, I did not understand what you meant by that a<=b

Comment: @Bernard Thank You. So you mean that in addition to the number, it also shows the order.

Comment: @tuna well I got a bit confused about transitivity of binary relation. Rob Arthan says that this notation for chains of binary relations is just a shorthand that is independent of the meaning of the relations. what is your opinion?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I got a bit confused about transitivity of binary relation. Rob Arthan says that this notation for chains of binary relations is just a shorthand that is independent of the meaning of the relations. what is your opinion?

Comment: @JairTaylor You mean a<b<c is a general form of 3 distinct number?

Comment: Actually, it's a condensed way to say: ‘ Let's consider 3 distinct numbers and denote denote $a$ the smallest, then $b$ and $c$ the largest’.

Comment: @MohammadMehdiSarfejoo Right, three distinct numbers must come in some order and we're just labeling first, second, third.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you so much for your detailed explanation.

Comment: @JairTaylor Thank you so much for your detailed explanation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A popular way to introduce numbers without any ordering is "Let $a,b,c \in (1,N)$". Or you could say "Let $a,b,c \in (1,N)$ be distinct" if you want to specify they're all different values.

The reason we can write $a = b = c$ or $a < b < c$ and it makes sense is because the binary relations $=$ and $<$ are transitive. E.g. $a < b$ and $ b < c$ implies $a < c$. The binary relation $\ne$ for example is not transitive. $1 \ne 2$ and $2 \ne 1$ does not imply that $1 \ne 1$. So statements like $a \ne b \ne c$ don't make sense.

Comment: Transitivity is irrelevant. This notation for chains of binary relations is just a shorthand that is independent of the meaning of the relations. The relations $<$ and $>$ are both transitive but I think you would deny the truth of  (the true statement) that  $1 < 2 > 1$. See my answer.

Comment: @RobArthan would You please explain more about 1<2>1? both of them are transitive But I think we can not conclude about the relationship between the two "1". am I right?

Comment: My comment on transitivity was chaining the same binary relation. Certainly people do chain different binary relations, such as $1 < 3 \le 5 = 5$. Rigorously I suppose chaining any binary relations is incorrect. But chaining a transitive binary relation is much more common because we read left to right, so any element relates to anything to the right of it in the chain. (I think this is the most common interpretation). Your interpretation is fine also as long as it's clear to the reader, but it seems strange to write something like $1 < 2 > 1$, something I've never seen used

Comment: I hope you don't mind I changed N to \mathbb{N}

Comment: I wish MSE allowed us to vote to close answers. Your answer makes misleading statements about standard mathematical terminology.

Comment: I disagree with the claim that $1<2>1$ and $a\ne b\ne c$ are standard uses of notation. In my experience, most math writers would avoid the former because it is "ugly" and the latter because it is ambiguous (suggesting to some readers that $a,b,c$ are all distinct, whether or not the notation actually means that). I agree with Brian: rigorously speaking, all instances of $a\,R\,b\,S\,c$ are abuse of notation, but this abuse is widely tolerated in the case where something like transitivity applies (implying a relation between $a$ and $c$), and not otherwise.

Comment: Honestly though, I will temper my opinion by saying that I have on occasion seen something like $x_1 \le x_2 \le \cdots \le x_{j-1} \le x_j \ge x_{j+1} \ge \cdots \ge x_n$ (as a way of saying "this sequence is unimodal"). So I suppose there is no absolute rule here, just a tradeoff between clarity and succinctness; the above notation is, to me, clear in intent in a way that $a\ne b\ne c$ isn't.

Comment: Why was $(1,N)$ changed to $(1,\mathbb{N})$? The former is (presumably) an open interval of real numbers. I have no idea what the latter means in this context.

Comment: @tuna: Thanks for providing the example about unimodality. When you think about that example, what do you think is really wrong with examples like $x \neq 0 \neq y$?

Comment: @Rob Arthan: In the specific instance of $x\ne 0\ne y$, I think the normal thing to write would be $x,y\ne 0$ (which is shorter anyway). As for $a\ne b\ne c$, like I said, the problem is that some readers may infer $a\ne c$ out of the habit formed by statements like $a<b<c$. Besides, I've seen students write $a\ne b\ne c$ when they meant "$a,b,c$ are all distinct", so at best it's going to make me stop and think "What is the author's intent here?" Good notation shouldn't make me do that more than is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

$a < b < c$ means that $a < b$ and $b < c$ both hold. In general, if $R$ and $S$ are binary relations then $a \mathrel{R} b \mathrel{S} c$ means $a \mathrel{R} b$ and $
b \mathrel{S} c$ both hold. Don't read any more into this kind of notation. E.g, you will occasionally see things like $a \neq b \neq c$: this doesn't preclude the possibility that $a = c$: $1 \neq 2\neq 1$ holds.

Comment: $b\ \mathrm{ S }\ c$

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: thanks for pointing out the typo.

Comment: I hate leaving posts with typos not corrected, so you are Mr. Arsehole to me$\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: it is a little bit confusing; because another answers were about transitivity of < and >. so You are saying this notation is just a shorthand and the only thing that we can figure out from this notation is that these are 3 distinct number and c is the largest and a is smallest. am I right?

Comment: You are reading too much into the notation and the other answer is misleading.